# Not a valid 2D array error in Javascript on IE8

Tags: javascript

I am getting 'not a valid 2D array' error in JavaScript on IE8. The script is working fine on Mozilla and other major browsers. I am using a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript.
Here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var new_arr = new Array();
  new_arr[1] = 0;
      new_arr[2] = 0;
      new_arr[3] = 0;new_arr[4] = 0;new_arr[5] = 0;new_arr[6] = 0;new_arr[7] = 0;new_arr[8] = 0;new_arr[9] = 0;new_arr[10] = 0;new_arr[11] = 0;new_arr[12] = 0;new_arr[13] = 0;new_arr[14] = 0;new_arr[15] = 0;new_arr[16] = 0;new_arr[17] = 0;new_arr[18] = 0;new_arr[19] = 0;new_arr[20] = 0;new_arr[21] = 0;new_arr[22] = 0;new_arr[23] = 0;new_arr[24] = 0;new_arr[25] = 0;new_arr[26] = 0;new_arr[27] = 0;new_arr[28] = 0;new_arr[29] = 0;new_arr[30] = 0;new_arr[31] = 0;   
 //var val = new Array();
 var val ='';

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
         ['Day', 'Answered Posts', 'Unanswered Posts'],
         ['1', 0,114],['2', 0,149],['3', 0,94],['4', 0,89],['5', 0,36],['6', 0,61],['7', 0,82],['8', 0,144],['9', 0,76],['10', 0,92],['11', 0,75],['12', 0,41],['13', 0,54],['14', 0,0],['15', 0,0],['16', 0,0],['17', 0,0],['18', 0,0],['19', 0,0],['20', 0,0],['21', 0,0],['22', 0,0],['23', 0,0],['24', 0,0],['25', 0,0],['26', 0,0],['27', 0,0],['28', 0,0],['29', 0,0],['30', 0,0],['31', 0,0],        ]);

    var options = {

      width: 940, 
      height: 334,
      min: 0, 
      max: 30,
      fontSize:10,
      chartArea:{width:800},
      colors: Array('#33CC00','#FF0000'),
      title: 'Posts In Current Month',
      titleTextStyle: {color: 'grey', fontSize: 14},
      hAxis: {maxAlternation: 1},   
      hAxis:{title: 'Day of Month',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#000000'}},
      tooltip:{textStyle: {color: '#000000'}, showColorCode: true},
      legend:{position: 'bottom', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 14}},
      vAxis:{title: 'No of Posts',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#000000'}},
      vAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: '#000000',
        count: 5
     }
   }
  };
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: We have to see the code in order to help in any specific way without wild guesses.  A common mistake in IE8 is adding an extra trailing comma after the last item in an array that IE8 will not accept, but other browsers will.

Comment: First wild stab in the dark: don't check using `indexOf`: IE8 doesn't support it

Comment: This error is coming from Google Charts...

Comment: I was having the exact same issue and after reading jfriend00's comment, I checked over my code.  I found a trailing comma after the second array being passed to Google Charts.  I removed that comma and now it works great in IE8.  If I could select that as the answer, I would.  I noticed in vishal's code that he/she has that trailing comma in the same spot I did.  I wonder if that fixed his/her issue too.

Answer (score 6):

in your code there is an error: You have a comma after the last position of the array, you should delete it.
Replace this:

```
['31 ', 0,0],
```

For this:

```
['31', 0,0]
```

Comment: This fixed the exact same problem for me on MSIE8 and below.